# Name "wmplayer" is not recognized as an executable file

Tags: powershell, path, environment-variables, cmd.exe

I cannot run wmplayer from either cmd or PowerShell. My OS is Windows 7 64 bit. I can do it using

```
start wmplayer
```

but I cannot use parameters. Please, help me to handle it.

Comment: see edited answer from @konqui below ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the current path does not contain `wmplayer` and if the `PATH` environment variable does not contain the path to `wmplayer`, you must provide the path to it on `start` command, as follows (as you can see in http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm):

```
 start /d "path_to_wmplayer" wmplayer
```

Generally, `path_to_wmplayer` is `c:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\`, so the solution for this case is:

```
 start /d "c:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\" wmplayer
```

Note: Use quotes `"` on the path and on the name of program/command called when they have spaces on them.

On this way you have to type the path every time you will launch it.

Other way, that is better when you often want to call `wmplayer`, is adding the path to it to `PATH` environment variable (system or user one). If you don't know how - take a look here http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/

Comment: Can you explain why `C:\> start wmplayer` works while `C:\> wmplayer` doesn't?

Comment: start is a built-in command into the cmd and it tells the cmd to do nothing else than a open/double click onto wmplayer. wmplayer alone its unknown so it uses it as a variable

Comment: Erm, what? How does that built-in start command know *where* to do this open/double click. Take notepad for example: Both methods work. So we can assume Windows stores the path to notepad.exe somewhere. Why not with wmplayer.exe?

Comment: cause the path of Notepad, CMD and some other exe are set in the path variable by default by Microsoft

Comment: No, as I know, start uses Windows Shell dll to run program (as Windows Explorer). So even if cmd doesn't know where is wmplayer, Start knows. Notepad is another case. It works, because it's in System32 (in x86) and System32 is already in cmd's environment variables (by default).

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how the CLI parses the command. When an absolute or relative path isn't specified, Windows uses its `PATH` and `PATHEXT` variables to find and execute a program. Sounds complicated, but it isn't. So when you enter in the command

```
Notepad
```

Windows first uses the path variable to look through a list of paths to see if there is a "notepad" object there. Let's say in your path variable (which you can view by typing `SET` into a command prompt and looking at the line that starts with `PATH=`) you have `C:\` and `C:\Windows\`, When you type notepad Windows first looks for

> C:\notepad *Nope, doesn't exist*

Then it tries

> C:\Windows\Notepad *Hey! There's something here!*

Now in answer to your question, when you enter in wmplayer by itself, Windows looks through `C:\` and `C:\Windows` (the values in your path variable) for a match, but since wmplayer is in Program Files, it's not going to find it. Now when you use `start wmplayer`, Windows uses a whole different set of variables to look through a list of installed programs for one with a name of wmplayer.

As for not being able to pass parameters, with start you can place any switches you like after the program name, like

> start notepad /a "C:\*somefile*"

Will open up *somefile* in notepad. If you want to do that without using start, the best way would be to enter the full path to the file followed by your parameters a la

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe *some parameters*

Comment: A bit better. But `when you use "start wmplayer", Windows uses a whole different set of variables` leads to the obvious question: Which variables? Can I see them somewhere in the registry? Are they stored in a DLL? :)

Comment: Default programs are stored in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\applications. If you look at the wmplayer key, it will show you the default command the shell will pass when you run the program via command line, Explorer or what have you.

Comment: +1 finally an explanation for that behavior. For what its worth: Under Win7 x64 the key says `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" /Open "%L"`

Comment: Glad I could help. The %L switch in the key is used by the shell to open associated files. So when you double click a .wma file, in the background the shell executes the command (%Program Files%\ ect.) and substitutes whatever you clicked on for %L.

Comment: The problem is I want to make a batch file that will run on 64 **and** 32 bit Windows. If I use `Program Files (x86)`, it won't work. The other thing is that you have to add a space between `Files` and `(x86)`. If there are spaces, you must "encapsule" the path in quotation marks.

Comment: Just have your script test if Program Files (x86) exists. If yes, have it run the statement for a 64 bit machine. Encapsulation won't be a big deal as long as you don't include your parameters in the quotations.